# Where to add #include <iostream> if my header file are already using std::cout

Tags: c++

I have a poor understanding of where to add `#include <iostream>` in project.

---

This is `LinkedList.h` , has a member function decleration `print_list()`

```
#include <iostream>

class LinkedList {
public:
    void print_list() const;
};
```

This is `LinkedList.cpp`, has the definition of member function.

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

void LinkedList::print_list() const
{
    // code prints something
    std::cout << "There is no element in list\n";
}
```

This is `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <LinkedList.h>

int main()
{
    // code
}
```

---

Question is, i do think that(might be wrong) only `main.cpp` file has to use `#include <iostream>`.

Can someone explain how to approach this situation and where to add `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Opinion based.   In general terms, it is better to not include any header in any header that does not actually *need* that header (in the sense that it won't compile without)   Since the definition of class `LinkedList` does not depend on `<iostream>`, there is no need for `LinkedList.h` to `#include <iostream>`.   It will then be necessary to `#include <iostream>` in any source file that uses facilities from that header - for example, in `LinkedList.cpp` at the top.   It is not necessary to `#include <iostream>` in `main.cpp` unless code in that file directly uses facilities from that header.

Comment: Including header unnecessarily (e.g.  headers that include lots of other headers "just in case") or in source files that don't need them won't usually prevent a project from building.   However, in larger projects, it is more likely to be a detriment.  I've seen cases in large projects where unnecessary inclusion of headers [admittedly, more headers than just `<iostream>`] increased (complete) build times from hours to days.

Comment: The principle is called "include what you use."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the header files in every file that directly uses something from the header. It is completely fine to include it multiple times that way. Standard library headers must be able to handle it and any other header should also be designed to support that. (That's what header guards are used for.)

That way it doesn't matter how you reorganize includes or your code. Every file always includes what it needs and so you are always safe. Adding includes in files that don't directly use something from the header becomes unnecessary.

So, in your case, only include `<iostream>` in `LinkedList.cpp` which actually uses `std::cout`. The order of includes is then not really relevant and mostly a style matter.

(This is only a general guideline though that should be mostly fine if you don't do anything unusual. Because `#include` is simply just literal inclusion of source code, there are certainly special cases that can occur.)

Comment: For reference: This paradigm is called include what you use (IWYU),
There are even [tools](https://include-what-you-use.org/) that can help to enforce that rule.

Answer (score 1):

This leans heavily toward opinion, but it seems reasonably safe to say that if you're using `<iostream>` features in `main`, then include it there. You should generally not count on a header file you're including to include some other header, unless the inclusion of that header is documented.

Including properly designed headers multiple times will not be an issue. This is what things like preprocessor guards are for.

As an addendum on design, `print_list` that's hard-coded to print to `std::cout` is not ideal. I would suggest either overloading `operator<<` so that you can print to *any* `std::ostream&`, or implementing iterators for your list which would permit a whole bunch of operations beyond just printing.

Comment: Or at a minimum allow the print function to take a stream as an argument. I don't like either solution, and would prefer to see proper iterators instead. It's not as if any of the `std::` containers can be directly printed.